# Increasing max. request length in asp.net 5 (vNext)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My problem is similar to the one described here:
[Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Since there is no web.config file in asp.net 5 (it is replaced by 'config.json' as far as I understand), how can one do this?

Also, if anyone found any documentation on the new 'config.json' file, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dealing with IIS then you still need web.config file to configure httpruntime.

You can add web.config to your solution. For that click on wwwroot folder and add web.config file over there.

After that you can provide your setting over there and it works with IIS just like it works for ASP.net 4.5.